# No records returned when search string has white space

Tags: sql-server

In the below query I have search query parameter as "Demo Test".
When I run the query I don't see the record. What am I missing ?

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(50)
DECLARE @startTime DATE
DECLARE @endTime DATE
SET @searchInput = 'Demo Test'
SET @startTime = '2018-09-02'
SET @endTime = '2018-09-12'
SELECT * FROM PatientDemoTable
WHERE  (@startTime IS NULL OR startdate >= @startTime)
AND (@endTime IS NULL OR enddate <= @endTime)
AND (patientFirstName like '%'+@searchInput+'%' 
OR patientMiddleName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
OR patientLastName like '%'+@searchInput+'%')
```

initial data:

```
INSERT INTO PatientDemoTable
    ([patientFirstName], [patientMiddleName], [patientLastName], [startdate], [enddate])
VALUES
    ('Patient', 'Demo', 'Test', '2018-09-02', '2018-09-08'),
    ('John', 'Doe', 'Demo', '2018-09-02', '2018-09-14'),
    ('Admin', 'Admin', 'Admin', '2018-09-07', '2018-09-20')
;
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db4db5/17

Comment: SQLFiddle seems to be down, can you add DDL and sample data to your question?

Comment: The SQLFiddle is blank

Comment: How would `Demo Test` match separate `Demo` and `Test` values in different columns? Probably you need to split user input value and upgrade your search mechanism to something more advanced.

Comment: Your search input is longer than any of the data you're comparing it to, so it (correctly) doesn't match anything. `%Demo Test%` will match neither `Demo` nor `Test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Diado said `'Demo' like '%Demo Test%'` will never match as you are searching for "Demo Test" string in the word "Demo" but the opposite way round will match i.e. `'Demo Test' like '%Demo%'`

Swap your searched fields around:

```
AND ( @searchInput like '%'+patientFirstName+'%'
OR @searchInput like '%'+ patientMiddleName +'%'
OR @searchInput like '%'+patientLastName+'%')
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use either Demo or Test as keyword in search input variable. Since, there is no word which contains DEMO TEST. Hence, it is not giving any result